# Is photo restoration on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

(This is spawned from: [What is the best way to remove texture from a scanned textured photo paper?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-texture-from-a-scanned-textured-photo-paper#comment39289_23445))

The question is pretty simple:

Is [photo restoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_restoration) on topic on this site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, the answer is a clear *yes*. Photo restoration is part of the broad domain of photography, just like the several [print preservation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-preservation) questions we already have.

This isn't graphic design or image manipulation, and it's not how-to-control-my-software. In fact, the techniques used here are pretty specific to photography. And unlike, for example, camera recommendations, the questions are likely to be specifically answerable.

Comment: I'd go with that myself (and it will tie in with a load of old negs I've inherited when I get the time to do *something* with them)

Comment: I'd have to agree.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Right on, thanks mattdm ;)

Comment: I'm going I go ahead and mark this as accepted, until such time as someone swoops in with a contrary answer convincing everyone otherwise. :)